# ScriptTask not opening VSTA IDE when you click edit. What could be wrong?

Tags: ssis

I have an SSIS package that contains a script task component, I did some coding inside to do data manipulation, it was working before but all of a sudden I can no longer open the VSTA code when clicking edit.

Comment: try opening visual studio in safe mode using the following command: `devenv.exe /safemode`

Comment: I did the easy way reverted my vm back to the snapshot when VSTA was still working.